# Does MongoDB provide a way to generate sequential values?

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I'm developing a web application in Java and storing some data on a MongoDB using Morphia.
Besides the `ObjectId`, I need to persist a sequential value for each document of a collection. This sequential value must be unique in the collection.

My first approach would be create a collection to store only the sequential value and synchronize the method which gets and increments the value.

Are there any better ways to do it?

Comment: Sure, there are other ways to do it... But I'd bet you already know this :) IMO I think the way you're implementing this makes sense and is a reasonable way to go.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'd like to make sure this is a good way and ask if there's better ways to do it.

Comment: We're doing something very similar (see https://github.com/xeraa/morphia-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/net/xeraa/morphia_demo/entities/AutoIncrementEntity.java). The nice thing about that implementation is that it can increment for the whole collection or a part of it (count employees per company for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally in MongoDB, you would not use an auto-increment pattern as it does not scale for databases with large numbers of documents. It is, however, possible to do this by using a separate counters collection to track the last number sequence used:

```
db.counters.insert(
  {
     _id: "userid",
      seq: 0
   }
  )
```

You can then create a function that will return you the next number in the sequence:

```
function getNextSequence(name) {
  var ret = db.counters.findAndModify(
         {
           query: { _id: name },
           update: { $inc: { seq: 1 } },
           new: true
         }
  );
```

Comment: See also the [page on the same](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/) in the MongoDB Manual.