# is this a correct why to create auto increment in mongodb ?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

is this a correct why to create auto increment method for every collection in mongodb ????

```
function counter(colName, callback)
    {
        MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db){
            db.collection(colName).find().count(callback);
        });

    }
    function myInsert(obj, colName)
    {
        MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db){
            counter(colName, function(err, data){
                obj._id=data+1;
                console.log(obj);
                db.collection(colName).insert(obj, function(err, res){
                    console.log("Inserted");
                }); 
            });

        });

    }
    myInsert({ "name" : "India" }, "hello");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does MongoDB provide a way to generate sequential values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29523127/does-mongodb-provide-a-way-to-generate-sequential-values)

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved via two methods.

1) [Counters Collection](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/#auto-increment-counters-collection)

Use a separate counters collection to track the last number sequence used. The _id field contains the sequence name and the seq field contains the last value of the sequence.

2) [Optimistic Loop](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/#auto-increment-optimistic-loop)

In this pattern, an Optimistic Loop calculates the incremented _id value and attempts to insert a document with the calculated _id value. If the insert is successful, the loop ends. Otherwise, the loop will iterate through possible _id values until the insert is successful.